# How to use getJSON on my html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm a totally noob on html, php, javascrpt... but I have enough programming skills, the fact is that I have the following code caught in google charts and slightly modified by me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization.1", {packages:["bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var datos = [
     ['DATOS', 'dato1', 'dato2', 'dato3', 'dato4'],
     ['22/03/2015', 1000, 400, 300, 1000],
     ['23/03/2015', 1170, 460, 250, 750],
     ['24/03/2015', 660, 220, 200, 730],
     ['25/03/2015', 200, 140, 100, 699]
    ];

    var datos_end = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datos);

    var options = {
    chart: {
    title: 'Datos de los sensores',
    }
};

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columncrt_material'));

chart.draw(datos_end, options);
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is: how can i get the data out from a .json file instead of writing manually. Data is already a string on the json file.

I've been seeing that there are functions to read a json with JQuery but i have not idea how to insert on my code:

```
var studentId = null;
j.getJSON(url, data, function(result)
{
    studentId = result.Something;
});
```

link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3...tjson-function

**EDIT**

My json is:

```
{
    "data":[
          ['DATA', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
          ['22/03/2015', 1000, 400, 300, 1000],
          ['23/03/2015', 1170, 460, 250, 750],
          ['24/03/2015', 660, 220, 200, 730],
          ['25/03/2015', 200, 140, 100, 2000]
        ]
}
```

Comment: You'd do it just like that, you've got it man! Of course, the issue is probably that you're trying to use `studentId` outside the callback, and *that* you can't do, as it's asynchronous.

Comment: Is your data barcoded into a JSON file? Or is the data being pulled from your database and you are creating the JSON from the data being retrieved? Once I know this, I can assist.

Comment: Where is that file? Served (e.g. via http) like the code you showed?

Comment: First, i don't use studentId of course hahhaa, th thing is that i don't know where to place that function in the code.
Second, data is in a JSON file, look the edit tag at the end, 
and third, the file is in the same path as the .php code, /var/www/html/graph.php and /var/www/html/datos.json

The real thing is i have some data with a time, and i want to add to my array, i mean, the json can be change to another file, just contained the data like this: 
    ['22/03/2015', 1, 2, 3, 4]
    ['23/03/2015', 10, 20, 250, 750]
line to line and i just need to read each line and add to my data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `$.getJSON` to parse the json file and assign the array to the datos_end.

First add the json in a file. I added as `graph.json` and store it in a place. Json must be in correct format. Don't copy and paste the above json content. Use the following json(formatted).

```
{"data":[["Year","Sales","Expenses","Profit"],["2014",1000,400,200],["2015",1170,460,250],["2016",660,1120,300],["2017",1030,540,350]]}
```

Then you need to add the [jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) to your page as like the google graph api file and then made some modification. Check the below code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <!-- Included Jquery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["bar"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            $.getJSON("graph.json", function(response){
                var datos_end = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response.data);

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Datos de los sensores',
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columncrt_material'));

                chart.draw(datos_end, options);
            })
            .success(function() { 
                console.log("success");
            })
            .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                console.log("error " + textStatus);
                console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);})
            .complete(function() {
                console.log("completed");
            });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columncrt_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more details about `$.getJson` check the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a real file, and you're using PHP and only need this to happen on the server side, you can just include it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization.1", {packages:["bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var datos = <?php include 'myJson.json'; ?>;

    var datos_end = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datos);

    var options = {
    chart: {
    title: 'Datos de los sensores',
    }
};

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columncrt_material'));

chart.draw(datos_end, options);
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated**: Put the code in the code of the original question

Comment: then, i can use json on function drawChart?? thank you!

Comment: and where i need to put that code?? before javascript scrpts??? sorry for my questions but i'm dummy on this kind of programming. thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I was lazy. I've updated my answer to fit into your original code. Just bear in mind this happens on the server side through PHP, and that file (`myJson.json` or whatever you call it) needs to exist.